# Rename first file only in multiple Subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I have a main directory with several differently named subdirectories, and I'm trying to find an easy way to rename the first file in those subdirectories to `First.txt`.

Example:

```
C:\Main
C:\Main\Folder1
C:\Main\Dir3
C:\Main\Place05
```

Take the first file in `Folder1`, `Dir3` and `Place05` and rename each to `First.txt`.

Comment: You're probably going to want a for loop with a rename and goto command.

Comment: With "First file" i mean the first "alphabetically a-z" file in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) for the task laid out in your question:

```bat
@For /D %%A In ("C:\Main\*")Do @Set "F="&For /F "EOL=?Delims=" %%B In ('Dir /B/A-L-S-D/ON "%%A" 2^>NUL')Do @If Not Defined F Set "F=1"&Ren "%%B" "First.txt"
```

To try to learn how it works, you can start by opening a Command Prompt window and reading the output from the following commands: `ren /?`, `set /?`, `if /?`, `dir /?`, and `for /?`

*The code above assumes that there isn't already a file named `First.txt` in any of the next level directories within `C:\Main`*

Comment: Thanks, will check above

Comment: When you say check, I'm assuming you mean run it, because if you had enough knowledge of batch files you'd have attempted to code it yourself. Remember that this answer was designed to achieve the task in your question. You could potentially replace `C:\Main\ ` and `First.txt`, but nothing else must be changed, or added before or after the line I have offered, when testing it. _I'm not supporting changes outside of the scope of your question at the time of posting._